# Unable to slideUp div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have downloaded the 1.11.3.min.js file and placed it in the same file where I have kept the HTML and script files. Before writing this code I have practiced jQuery a lot and those time I have succeeded, but this time I can't run it.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
     <head>  
     <!---<script type="text/javascript" src="image.js"></script---->

    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.js"></script>
     <!---<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image.css">---->
     </head>
     <body onload="slideimage()">


      <img src="1.jpg" id="slide" width="400px" height="400px"/>

      <div id="button">
    `enter code here`<button onclick="change_image()" />1</button>
    </div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

jQuery

```
 $document.ready(function(){
    $("#slide").click(function(){

        $(this).slideUp(400);

    });
 });
```

I have downloaded the 1.11.3.min.js file and put in the same file where i have kept the HTML and script files.Before writing this code i have practiced jQuery a lot and those time i have  succeeded.But this time i have failed to run it.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this line of code

```
$document.ready(function(){
```

with this line

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

You did't add brackets around `document`

Answer (score 0):

May be you want do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#slide").click(function(){

        $(this).slideUp(400);

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using CDN's for jQuery (less loading time), it can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then, you forgot to end your function, and you forgot `()` around `document` 
your script should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#slide").click(function() {

        $(this).slideUp(400);

    });
});
```